# Jenkins uses default ruby but not from RVM

Tags: jenkins, path, rvm, environment

I have Jenkins automation server that connects to my machine through `ssh` with user `snaggs`.

My machine has 2 versions of `ruby`:

- default version comes from OS `/System/Library/Frameworks/ ..... /usr/bin/ruby`
- `ruby` v2.3.3 installed with [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

  On machine the automation runs some Perl script with some commands. `whoami` from jenkins gives `snaggs`

When Perl script runs command `gem env` the output is:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-12-16 patchlevel 648) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/snaggs/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
```

---

**However when I enter to the same machine with `ssh` to the same user `snaggs` I have `ruby` version installed with `rvm`:**

When I run `$ gem env` I get output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/snaggs/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/snaggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/snaggs/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/snaggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3
     - /Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin
     - /Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@global/bin
     - /Users/snaggs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/snaggs/.rvm/bin
```

How to tell to Jenkins to use other version located under  `/Users/snaggs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3`?

**[EDIT]**

I **don't** run script as super user

Comment: Looks like PATH is not set as expected. How about using the [rvm plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RVM+Plugin)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem when tried to configure Java version.

Take a look at [Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SSH+Slaves+plugin#SSHSlavesplugin-Loginprofilefiles):

> When the SSH slaves plugin connects to a slave, it does not run an
>   interactive shell. Instead, it does the equivalent of your running "ssh
>   slavehost command..."

So suppose when you will run `gem env` from ssh, you should get the same result like Jenkins gets: `ssh snaggs@1.1.1.1 "gem env"`

> On machine the automation runs some Perl script with some commands.

You can try to create some custom `.bash_profile_CUSTOM` that equals to your original `.bash_profile` You need to call `.bash_profile_CUSTOM` because Jenkins uses *own* `.bash_profile` by default .Run your perl script like:

```
ssh snaggs@1.1.1.1 "source ~/.bash_profile_CUSTOM && perl some_perl_script.pl"
```

Just remember that you need to *bind* `bash_profile_CUSTOM` file each time Jenkins connects to your build machine. So from Jenkins the command executable should be something like:

```
source ~/.bash_profile_CUSTOM && perl some_perl_script.pl
```

let me know if it works or give you different output

---

*Edit: (25/12/2016)*

If you don't want to install plugins for Jenkins (like [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) for  Prefix Start Slave Command) you can wrap Perl script with bash script, like:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/. bash_profile_CUSTOM;

perl some_perl_script.pl;
```

So Perl script will start with profile you defined with `.bash_profile_CUSTOM`.

Comment: looks like your solutions  (with bash script) makes sense, i created `.bash_profile_CUSTOM` and it works from ssh. yay :).  I need also write full path for `perl`. Im working on bash now, need to fetch exit code from Perl. You saved me several days, thank you

Comment: Still have some issues with Jenkins but its my side

Comment: @snaggs, ok, I don't have your environment so for sure you can do your homework. I posted the concept that worked for me. good luck